# Managed Metadata field full path

Tags: 2010, managed-metadata, column, xml

I've added a custom Managed Metadata field in my custom contenttype but need to show the **full path**. Anyone knows how to do this? (if possible with xml, else with c#)

**XML so far:**

```
  <Field ID="{0DEB6928-56E5-4E36-B2C7-75C1F0A7D49C}" Name="Process0" DisplayName="Process_0" StaticName="Process0" Group="Sioen" Type="Note" ShowInViewForms="FALSE" Hidden="TRUE" CanToggleHidden="TRUE" RowOrdinal="0" DisplaceOnUpgrade="TRUE" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/"/>
  <Field ID="{D1F39E25-9DB1-49FA-B7A2-993795A1251F}" Name="Process"  DisplayName="Process" StaticName="Process" Group="Sioen" Type="TaxonomyFieldType" Required="TRUE" ShowField="Path1033" DisplaceOnUpgrade="TRUE" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <Customization>
      <ArrayOfProperty>
        <Property>
          <Name>TextField</Name>
          <Value xmlns:q6="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q6:string" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">{0DEB6928-56E5-4E36-B2C7-75C1F0A7D49C}</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property>
          <Name>IsPathRendered</Name>
          <Value xmlns:q7="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q7:boolean" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">true</Value>
        </Property>
      </ArrayOfProperty>
    </Customization>
  </Field>
```

Comment: This was very helpful. However, I was a little thrown since **the question now contains the correct XML** (edited after the answer was provided). Just a heads up for those that come after me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following property to ArrayOfProperty

```
<Property>
    <Name>IsPathRendered</Name>
    <Value xmlns:q7="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q7:boolean" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">true</Value>
</Property>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this doesn't seem to work. Are there other things I need to change?

Comment: Also, I guess you added the showfield (in your 2nd code example) was added on the wrong field? Or am I wrong?

Comment: PS. I've updated my xml code in my question

Comment: IsPathRendendered should have done it, the rest of the definitions in both posts look right.

Comment: AFAIK the ShowField should be Term1033 as in original question, not Path1033, and certainly on the TaxonomyFieldType (not the Note, which does not have that attribute). Actually if you really want to support multilingual it should be literally: ShowField="Term$Resources:core,Language;".

Comment: Ruben: You're right, corrected.

Comment: I agree that IsPathRendered should do it. I was noticing that the value of ShowField changed when changing the field to display path. I'll investigate further.

Comment: Can you please provide some detailed explanation on why "Path1033" should be used ? I've never heard of this property and the amount of hits on google are pretty questonable in my opinion.

Comment: I've removed that part of the answer now. Like I said in my previous comment, I noticed the ShowField was updated when I changed the field to show metadata path. I can't find any resources on it though, so I'm removing it.